# Google plus like layout using Angular Material 2 Grid list

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I am trying to make a "Google Plus like" multi-column responsive page layout with angular and flex-layout.

I have the responsive multi columns working
but how to arrange the row layout that it stacks? I am trying but this doesn't "stack" the cards.

Comment: can u pls post the code of `responsive multi columns`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called **masonry**.

I guess you are looking for something like:

- https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry

or

- https://masonry.desandro.com/

if you search for "pinterest like layout" you will get more hits :)